# OKTA Unable to generate Session from Session Token - Postman

Tags: session, okta

Using the provided environment and collections from Okta in Postman, I run "Primary Authentication with Trusted Application" and Authenticate with no issues. I then copy and set my SessionToken. When I try to then  "Create Session with Session Token" it always fails with:

```
{
  "errorCode": "E0000004",
  "errorSummary": "Authentication failed",
  "errorLink": "E0000004",
  "errorId": "oaeDAJpYgLNQS6AnhFwQ3QLcA",
  "errorCauses": []
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? The example Postman call for "Create Session with Session Token" only shows the SessionToken being passed in. I shouldn't need to authenticate again?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Postman and starting fresh and following http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/api_test_client.html worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing the right thing here, but please note that you can only call the "Create Session with Session Token" endpoint once. If you call it twice (or more), you will end up with the E000004 error you mentioned.

If you are positive that you only tried this one, instead of copying the sessionToken value you get back from the Primary Authentication call (you can try that one too instead of "Primary Authentication with Trusted Application") into the sessionToken variable, try to copy and paste it directly into the Body of the "Create Session with Session Token" field by replacing the {{sessionToken}} placeholder with your session token value.

Please let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi Raphael, Thanks for the response. Just tried this morning. Did one "Primary Authentication w trusted" call copied the SessionToken from the response, and then tried "Create Session with Session Token" and pasted the SessionToken replacing {{sessionToken}}. I am still getting "Authentication failed". Also tried the regular "Primary Authentication" and copied the SessionToken from the response and tried the "Create Session w Session Token" and I get "Invalid Session". :(

Comment: Ryan, you originally wrote that you are using the "provided environments and collections from Okta in Postman". Did you make sure that you updated the url, apikey and subdomain properties with valid values in your selected Postman environment?

Comment: Sure did. Like I said the Authentication Calls work no problem. It is just when I take the SessionToken I get back from my "SUCCESS" response and try it in "Create Session w Session Token" I get errors & neither work. Followed instructions here: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/api_test_client.html

Comment: Hi Ryan, did you try calling another endpoint in Postman, such as List Users, without even first calling the Primary Authentication API?

If you have a valid apikey value in your Postman environment, you don't even need to call the Authentication API first, since the apikey authenticates you seamlessly. You will probably notice that the Authentication API actually works without a valid apikey parameter (provided you provide valid Okta credentials, of course). So in your situation, I'm wondering if you're actually using a valid apikey or not. If not, is there a reason why you made that choice?

Comment: Hi Raphael, I ended up getting it to work by removing postman and starting fresh. Not sure what may have caused the issue but it is working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Ryan, glad to know you eventually got it to work! Good luck and let us know if you have any other question here or at developers@okta.com

Answer (score 0):

The `error code "E0000004"` is returned in case of following possible conditions:

- Locked out accounts
- Invalid credentials
- Access denied by a sign-on policy

The `errorSummary` will be `"Authentication failed"` only to prevent brute force attacks by not providing much information.